# Declare place holder with auto_increment in mysql database

Tags: mysql

If `id` is set as an auto_increment in mysql database then how should we declare place holder?

This is my code:

```
 String sql="update bed set(bedname=?, bedprice=?, description=?, filename=?, path=? where id=?)";
          PreparedStatement pst= con.prepareStatement(sql);

          pst.setString(1, bdname);
          pst.setString(2, bdprice);
          pst.setString(3, desc);
          pst.setString(4, fileName);
          pst.setString(5, savePath);
          pst.setInt(6,     )    // what we have to put here ???

          int i=pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Why do you have brackets around the assignment list? Shouldn't it be `UPDATE bed SET bedname=?, bedprice=?....` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your field to auto-increment, then no need to specify any prepared statement for it. but if you want to update specific row then you have to provide id number also.

Comment: String sql="update bed set(bedname=?, bedprice=?, description=?, filename=?, path=?)"+"values(?,?,?,?,?)";
              PreparedStatement pst= con.prepareStatement(sql);
               
              pst.setString(1, bdname);
              pst.setString(2, bdprice);
              pst.setString(3, desc);
              pst.setString(4, fileName);
              pst.setString(5, savePath);
              
              
         
                int i=pst.executeUpdate();

Comment: but i am getting a sql exception like this.... com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(bedname='lunar', bedprice='25000', description='hi', filename='showcase 1.jpg',' at line 1

Comment: plzcheck is this correct...String sql="update bed set(bedname=?, bedprice=?, description=?, filename=?, path=?)";

Comment: @syed Which record you want to update ? You need to specify id number. pst.setInt(6,     )  pass here id number you want to update. and also remove int i from execute statement. just write pst.executeUpdate();

Comment: i cannot pass id number manually .... it's a webApp... how can a client enter an id number ....  ??? let me know

Comment: @syed Which record you want to update ? how do you came to know ?

Comment: i am creating a web app... and i want my client to update a row from jsp page ....

Comment: plz let me know ...its very important

Comment: You have id field containing auto increment value . Hence every row contains unique number . You have to pass that number here